# Проблемы с добавлением Toolbar в android-приложение

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Я попытался добавить `Toolbar` в свое android-приложение и при объявлении и инициализации возникли кое-какие проблемы. А именно:

При выполнении этого кода возникает ошибка:

> Class requires API level 21 (current min is 15): android.widget.Toolbar

Код:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolBar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: ошибки нужно писать текстом, а не скриншотами - это позволит другим легче найти решение аналогичной проблемы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Текст вашей ошибки говорит о том, что используемый вами класс `Toolbar` можно использовать только с минимальной версией API проекта `21`, а у вас в проекте установлена `15`.

Вы используете `android.widget.Toolbar`, а для использования начиная с `14` версии API нужен `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

Чтобы его использовать, подключите в зависимостях в `build.gradle` для вашего модуля:

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
```